# Убрать блок при клике на любую область вокруг. jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, javascript, css

Всех приветствую.

Я написал простенький скрипт

```
$(function() {
    $("#uuser").click(function() {
        $("#uuser_b > ul").animate({
            opacity: "toggle"
        }, 200);
    });
});
```

Просто добавляем или прячем блок при клике на #uuser. Как сделать так, чтобы если я нажимал на любое пространство вокруг #uuser_b > ul, то этот блок прятался?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).is("#uuser_b > ul, #uuser")) {
         $("#uuser_b > ul").animate({opacity: 0});
    }
});

$("#uuser").click(function() {
    $("#uuser_b > ul").animate({
        opacity: 1
    }, 200);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FqhpK/18/

Comment: Во второй строке наверно лучше так проверять:

    if (!$(e.target).is("#uuser_b, #uuser_b *, #uuser"))

Comment: @Bars нет, не лучше. В вашем случае 3 итерации.

Comment: когда мы на one, two, three в вашем примере, они исчезают. А это плохо

Comment: @inferus-vv, Так там только селектор чуть подправить надо. [Смотрим тут](http://jsfiddle.net/FqhpK/19/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $("#uuser").click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $("#uuser_b > ul").animate({
            opacity: "toggle"
        }, 200);
    });
});
```

не проверял в работе

Comment: Не работает